# oData service sequence of calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, service, odata

How to make sequential async requests in chunks of 50 records to a oData service.

```
 (function () {
    // Multiple api calls
    var oData = "http://localhost:8888/Clinics";
    fetch(oData)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            var nextLink = data['@@odata.nextLink'];
            console.log(data);

        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });


})();
```

I would like to make the next call after I revive the previous data. The idea is to display data in parts. My code returns the first 50 records and the next link successful. I would l like to know how can I effectively make the next sequential requests.

Comment: Does your odata service returns 50 over data?

Comment: @ahmeticat it does return the fist 50 records from the first page and the nextLink "http://localhost:8888/Clinics?$skip=50"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to achieve the result calling the function recursively. I´m sure there is a more effective way to achieve the same results.

```
function oDataCall(nextLink) {
    oData = nextLink;
        fetch(oData)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();                   
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                nextDataLink = data['@@odata.nextLink'];
                if (typeof nextDataLink === "undefined") {
                    eod = true;
                } else {
                    console.log(nextDataLink);
                    oDataCall(nextDataLink);
                }                      

            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("error: ", err);
            });       

}      

oDataCall("http://localhost:8888/Clinics");
```